# How to write case insensitive order query in sequelize(SQLite)?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am trying to order by my data based on an attribute. Here I have a model name **Farmer** and I am ordering this model by name. The query is like this:

```
Farmer.findAll({order: [['name', 'ASC']]})
```

Which is ordering data case sensitively. But I want to order this case insensitively. How can i get it?

Comment: Ordering is depending on the Collation of the column, not on Sequelize or some other ORM package. What Collation is set for this column? See the structure of Table via Phpmyadmin or something.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sequelize.fn` ([http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-fn](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-fn)) to transform your name to lowercase

```js
Farmer.findAll({
  order: [
    [
      Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('name')),
      'ASC',
    ],
  ],
});
```

Comment: please explain how to use `fn` along with `order`.

Comment: @YousufKhan I just updated my answer to include an example